# Wordpress Blog page a:visited and category tags invisible 'white'

Tags: css, wordpress, class, blogs

I've built a wordpress theme from scratch however style the bootstrap navigation to white text and brown text on selection - this appears to be overiding the a: visit and a: hover on everything i've tried to add a separate new a class for the H1 tags on the blog post page but it doesn't appear to work I've used.

```
.h1blog{
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family:"Lato", arial, helvetica, sans serif;
    color:#674922;
    line-height:120%;
}

a.h1blog:link{ color: #674922; text-decoration: none; }

a.h1blog:visited{ color: #666666; text-decoration: none; }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated i've even tried some class styling against the preset classes in wordpress but this doesn't work either?

http://creative-media.info/WarringtonBonsai/latest-news-offers/

cheers

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
<h1 class="h1blog"><a href="http://creative-media.info/WarringtonBonsai/test-3/">TEST 3</a></h1>
```

You have an `<h1>` element with the `h1blog` class, containing an `<a>` element that you're trying to style with this rule:

```
a.h1blog:link{ color: #674922; text-decoration: none; }
```

That won't work, because the `<a>` element doesn't have the `h1blog` class applied to it. Try this instead:

```
.h1blog a:link{ color: #674922; text-decoration: none; }
```